# Get params URL with Sveltekit endpoint

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to get the params in my URL for an API endpoints I coded with SvelteKit.

I wanted to use the stores for that:

`import {page } from '$app/stores';`

and then, in my GET endpoint:

```
export async function get({ request, params }) {
    const path = params.auth;
    console.log($page.URL);
…
```

Svelte gives me an error with: `$page is not defined`

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `page` store is only supposed to be used in a Svelte component. In your endpoint, the URL can be accessed via the `url` property on the event passed to the function.

```js
export async function get({ request, params, url }) {
    console.log(url);
    // etc.
}
```